# Android - get Gender and BirthDate from Google Plus using OAuth 2.0 & Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, oauth-2.0, google-play-services, google-plus

I have only copied setUp function from " [get ready to use the api](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/getting-started) " People API  and  I followed the steps listed it.
I've added my clientid and my secretid but i have always the same error.
i try to get   information about profil user (specifically gender and age) from google plus account to classify users.

Google authentification linked to Firebase works perfectly and gives me name, mail and Photourl. but when i try to connect to google plus using  OAuth 2.0 - Google ,It's not working

--> I don't understand why CODE is always null

```
    String redirectUrl = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
    String scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly";

    // Step 1: Authorize -->
    String authorizationUrl =
            new GoogleBrowserClientRequestUrl(clientId, redirectUrl, 
    Arrays.asList(scope)).build();

    // Point or redirect your user to the authorizationUrl.
    System.out.println("Go to the following link in your browser:");
    System.out.println(authorizationUrl);

    // Read the authorization code from the standard input stream.
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("What is the authorization code?");
    String code = in.readLine();
```

Manifest File :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
```

Build.grale :

```
configurations {
all {
    exclude module: 'httpclient'
}
}
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:12.0.1'
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-people:v1-rev229-1.23.0'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:12.0.1'
compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.23.0'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.1'
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```

Logcat :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ .SecondActivity20paste}: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496)
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386)
                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                      at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:213)
                                                                      at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127)
                                                                      at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.setCode(AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:147)
                                                                      at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.setCode(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:147)
                                                                      at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.setCode(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:79)
                                                                      at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.<init>(AuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:103)
                                                                      at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.<init>(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:111)
                                                                      at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.<init>(GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest.java:92)
                                                                      at com.teeen.user.teeen.SecondActivity20paste.setUp(SecondActivity20paste.java:561)
                                                                      at com.teeen.user.teeen.SecondActivity20paste.onCreate(SecondActivity20paste.java:176)
                                                                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6955)
                                                                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642) 
                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776) 
                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1496) 
                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1386) 
04-04 10:24:25.336 25756-25785/com. W/MessengerIpcClient: Timing out request: 1
04-04 10:24:25.338 25756-25784/com. E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
04-04 10:25:25.375 25756-25784/com. E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
```

Please help me how to resolve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: At which line of code are you getting NPE?

Comment: at  GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest ;  authorization code is always null i don't undertand why ? i try to get profile information from  PeopleService.
  GoogleTokenResponse tokenResponse = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(   httpTransport, jsonFactory, clientId, clientSecret, code, redirectUrl).execute();